# Forcing two similar classes to behave as if they were polymorphic in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

**Abstract:**

I would like to interact with two classes ('Item' and 'Block') that share many similar functions as if they were implemented from an interface with these functions, however they are not and I can not edit them. What are my options for dealing with this? Am I stuck writing super hacky code?

**Details:**

I am working on a minecraft mod in Java, part of working with minecraft is that I can not edit the base code of the game. There are two fundamental classes to the game; "Block" and "Item", both of these share a number of functions however the developers did not make them implement an interface (as I wish they had).

To keep my code clean and avoid a lot of if statements switching between handling Blocks and Items I would like to keep both in a generic list, preferably casting to Block or Item as little as possible, and while attempting to maintain readability.

My current solution fails to satisfy as a good one, it's hard to read and while it cleans up some code duplication I still have to cast return types.

**Update:**

Based on the answer left by [Eran](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26212452/4112078) I have updated my solution to this problem and I now find this to be satisfactory:

I created adapter (taking the adapter name as suggested in comments) classes that interfaced with an ItemOrBlockAdapter and extended Block and Item:

```
public interface ItemOrBlockAdapter {
    public String myGetUnlocalizedName();
    public ItemOrBlockAdapter mySetCreativeTab(CreativeTabs tab);
}

public class BlockAdapter extends Block implements ItemOrBlockAdapter {
    protected BlockAdapter(String uid, Material m) {
        super(m);
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(this, uid);
    }

    public String myGetUnlocalizedName()
    {
        return this.getUnlocalizedName();
    }

    public ItemOrBlockAdapter mySetCreativeTab(CreativeTabs tab)
    {
        return (ItemOrBlockAdapter)this.setCreativeTab(tab);
    }
}
```

This is a lot better than the hacky solution I used before (looking through Block and Item methods to find the desired method every call)! However it is not without fault, I now have to write every function I wish to add an adapter for three times, and a fourth time if something else inherits the head adapter.

I consider this solved but I'm open to superior solutions since this involves quite a lot of code duplication (Understand that I will have to add a lot of methods to make this complete, not just two as shown above).

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning this here as well: This is basically what is sometimes called *"Duck Typing"*, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can Create wrapper classes - `BlockWrapper` and `ItemWrapper`. Both would implement the same interface (which would contain the common methods of `Block` and `Item`). `BlockWrapper` would contain a `Block` instance and `ItemWrapper` would contain an `Item` instance.

Example :

```
public interface ItemOrBlock // think of a better name
{
    public void func1();

    public void func2();
}

public class BlockWrapper implements ItemOrBlock 
{
    private Block block;

    public BlockWrapper (Block block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    public void func1()
    {
        block.func1();
    }

    public void func2()
    {
        block.func2();
    }

}
```

`ItemWrapper` would have a similar implementation.

Now, if you create `BlockWrapper`s and `ItemWrapper`s from the `Block`s and `Item`s, you can put them in a Collection of `ItemOrBlock`, and use that interface to call their common methods.

Comment: That works for 95% of my problem so thanks! I have a couple of functions I'm not sure that will work for as written just yet, I'll test them out and then mark this as solved.

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes You're welcome! What are the remaining 5%?

Comment: Adapter is the pattern name for this. Wrapper's not incorrect, but is a more general term.

Comment: Looks like the Adapter pattern to me too. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: I've amended my original post after attempting this in my code, I actually extended Block and Item with the adapter rather than just containing a Block or Item. As far as I can tell the term "adapter" still applies to the solution I adapted from yours ;) The remaining 5% is that this has a lot of code duplication, which is one of the things I set out to avoid.

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes Extending the classes may seem tempting, since it involves less code to write in the sub-classes (since the methods of the interface are already implemented by the super-classes), but I still think composition is the correct solution here, and not inheritance. What do you do when you get an instance of Block? Do you create an instance of "SubBlock" with a copy constructor that copies all the Block properties? Don't you still have to keep the original Block instance somewhere?

Comment: @Eran Since Block and Item should be inheriting common properties in the first place, going back and defining those common properties with inheritance seems ok, however I admit composition might be a tad more professional? In this less abstract practical application I don't see my self running into that finer detail, It's ideal in my application for the objects I'm working with to resolve directly to an Item or a Block, and inheriting Item or Block is used typically in this situation. In my case I have a bunch of Block or Item inheriting classes that I want to all fit into an ArrayList.

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes That's OK if your code is the only producer of Blocks and Items. If you get from some other code instances of Block and Item that are not instances of your sub-classes, you'll have to create new instances from them in order to work with the common interface.

Comment: @Eran Yes, however isn't that also true of the method you described?

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes Yes, but in my method, you only wrap the original instance with the new instance. The original instance is still available within the wrapper. In your solution, you create a new instance based on the original one, but the new instance has no reference to the original instance. I don't know if it matters in your use case, but it might.

Comment: @Eran Good to know, in my case it happens to not matter, I simply needed something that acts totally like a Block or Item given the situation, but I'll amend my question soon to be more explicit about the drawbacks of my implementation and clearer on your suggestions! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Although the question already has an accepted answer, I'd like to mention the option of creating [Dynamic Proxy Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html).

One could argue that this is only a way of "hiding" the ugly reflection code, it is a neat and elegant solution, and compared to manually creating adapter/wrapper classes, it has one striking advantage for similar use cases: You can create delegates of one interface for *many* classes, without having to hard-code the repetitive boilerplate code for each class that is "not-implementing" the interface.

The follwing is a simple example, based on the delegator from the above mentioned link:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;

public class DynamicProxyExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Block block = new Block();
        Item item = new Item();

        Entity blockEntity = asEntity(block);
        Entity itemEntity = asEntity(item);

        blockEntity.setName("Block");
        System.out.println(blockEntity.getName()+", "+blockEntity.computeSize());

        itemEntity.setName("Item");
        System.out.println(itemEntity.getName()+", "+itemEntity.computeSize());

    }

    private static Entity asEntity(Object object)
    {
        Class<?>[] ifs = new Class<?>[] { Entity.class };
        Entity entity = (Entity) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            Entity.class.getClassLoader(), ifs, 
            new Delegator(object));
        return entity;
    }
}

class Delegator implements InvocationHandler
{
    private static Method hashCodeMethod;
    private static Method equalsMethod;
    private static Method toStringMethod;
    static
    {
        try
        {
            hashCodeMethod = Object.class.getMethod("hashCode",
                (Class<?>[]) null);
            equalsMethod = Object.class.getMethod("equals",
                new Class[] { Object.class });
            toStringMethod = Object.class.getMethod("toString",
                (Class<?>[]) null);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
        {
            throw new NoSuchMethodError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private final Object delegate;

    Delegator(Object delegate)
    {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)
        throws Throwable
    {
        Class<?> declaringClass = m.getDeclaringClass();
        if (declaringClass == Object.class)
        {
            if (m.equals(hashCodeMethod))
            {
                return proxyHashCode(proxy);
            }
            else if (m.equals(equalsMethod))
            {
                return proxyEquals(proxy, args[0]);
            }
            else if (m.equals(toStringMethod))
            {
                return proxyToString(proxy);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InternalError(
                    "unexpected Object method dispatched: " + m);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Class<? extends Object> delegateClass = delegate.getClass();
                Method delegateMethod = delegateClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                    m.getName(),  m.getParameterTypes());
                return delegateMethod.invoke(delegate, args);
            }
            catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                throw e.getTargetException();
            }
        }
    }

    protected Integer proxyHashCode(Object proxy)
    {
        return new Integer(System.identityHashCode(proxy));
    }

    protected Boolean proxyEquals(Object proxy, Object other)
    {
        return (proxy == other ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    protected String proxyToString(Object proxy)
    {
        return proxy.getClass().getName() + '@' +
            Integer.toHexString(proxy.hashCode());
    }
}


class Item
{
    private String name;

    void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    int computeSize()
    {
        return 12;
    }
}

class Block
{
    private String name;

    void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    int computeSize()
    {
        return 23;
    }
}

interface Entity
{
    void setName(String name);

    String getName();

    int computeSize();

}
```

(of course, some better error handling could be inserted, but it shows the basic approach)

---

EDIT To elaborate this further, partially in response to the comment:

As I mentioned, this could be considered as only "hiding" the nasty reflection parts. And one still has to cope with the usual reflection issues, like a more difficult error handling and missing compile-time error checks.

But for more complex setups, it could be advantageous: Imagine there are more than two classes, and more than one "not-implemented" interface. Then manually coding the glue code in form of wrapper/adapter classes could be cumbersome.

However, I like the simplicity of Dynamic Proxy Classes. They are the only feasible way to achieve something like [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in Java - and they just work magically.

Comment: This seems more like the solution I was building to with reflection however much more elegant, I'll give it an attempt to see if it solves my code duplication woes and return with news of it's success. First however I have to read your link to understand any of that!

Comment: @AlexeiBarnes I added a small EDIT. What you are looking for is actually called "Duck Typing" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing ), and proxies are one approach for achieving this in Java (there's also an example on the Wikipedia page)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've actually read about Duck Typing and used it in C++, however my mind had melted away the concept over time and I had completely forgotten the idiom I was using! The wikipedia example is much more readable so I think I understand enough of this to consider using it now.